# jQuery generated <a> not clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To save data flow I use these lines to wrap text in a pattern with anchors, the code executed successfully, but why it seems that the generated anchors are not clickable?

```
$(function(){
    $(".block span").each(function(){
        $(this).wrapInner("<a></a>")
        $(this).find("a").attr("herf","/tag/"+encodeURIComponent($(this).html()));
    })
})
```

**And you could also see jsfiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/vftMe/**
Is there any error in my code? Or it's just the browser's limit? What's the alternative way to do this?

Comment: You have a simple typo in your code. The odds of this answer being useful to anybody in the future are almost zero, voted to close as too localized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`herf` should be `href`:

```
$(function(){
    $(".block span").each(function(){
        $(this).wrapInner("<a></a>")
        $(this).find("a").attr("href","/tag/"+encodeURIComponent($(this).html()));
    })
})
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/94X72/

Comment: Can't believe that's the error,down voted for myself. These errors not in firebug are not so obvious. Thank you.

Comment: You probably want to use `.text()`, not `.html`. Otherwise the anchor tag will get caught in the link.

Comment: @vsjones I found this problem too, I changed wrapInner() with wrap() and find() with parent().

Answer (score 2):

it must be href not herf

> $(this).find("a").attr("href","/tag/"+encodeURIComponent($(this).html()));

Answer (score 2):

Just a typo:

herf has to be href: http://jsfiddle.net/vftMe/2/

Answer (score 1):

You've typed href as herf. Try the following:

```
$(function(){
$(".block span").each(function(){
    $(this).wrapInner("<a></a>")
    $(this).find("a").attr("href","/tag/"+encodeURIComponent($(this).html()));
})
```

})